# Can Mono DataConvert be used to read a 3-byte integer?

Tags: c#, mono, data-conversion, endianness

I'm trying to read a particular binary file, but it contains 3-byte big-endian integers. I came across [Mono DataConvert](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert) recently, which should be nice for most of what I want, except for these 3-byte integers. I'm not sure how to read them. Note that I don't need to keep them as 3-byte integers, reading them into a regular `Int32` would be ideal. I'm reading in a good chunk of data, so I'm looking for something efficient. Any suggestions?

---

Sample ideal code:

```
public Region(string regionFile)
{
    var conv = DataConverter.BigEndian;
    var chunks = new Chunk[Chunk.MaxLocations];
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(regionFile))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // Read chunk locations
        for (int i = 0; i < Chunk.MaxLocations; ++i)
        {
            chunks[i] = new Chunk(conv.ToInt24(buffer, i * 4), buffer[i * 4 + 3]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something like that, except `conv.ToInt24` doesn't exist. I guess I could write my own by bit-shifting...

Comment: Do you know the format of the 3 byte ints? Is it identical to a standard int with an extra byte?

Comment: @M.Babcock: Seems to be, yes. Except it's Big Endian, and I need to convert it to my native format (Little Endian). If I could pad it with an extra 0-byte, I'd be able to read to nicely, but I'm not sure of a nice way to do that. I want to read in a chunk of the file (say 4 KiB) and then loop over it, converting the different parts as necessary. Normally I'd just call `converter.GetInt32(theData, myOffset)` but then it will read into the next byte, which won't work.

Comment: It doesn't appear this is supported by `Mono.DataConvert` out of the box (as one should expect), but it shouldn't be too difficult to define a 3 byte struct that will do the conversion for you. It sounds like a fun project anyway (shouldn't be any harder than the rolling 7 bit int I had to use to get RTMP to work). Considering you said it is an `int` I assume the typical two's complement signage applies, correct? \

Comment: @M.Babcock: Spec doesn't say specifically, but this `(data[index + 0] << 16) + (data[index + 1] << 8) + data[index + 2]` seems to yield sensible results, so I'm going to go ahead and say "Yes". You think some "union" hackery would be more efficient?

Comment: That is how I would do it in C++. I can't speak to whether there is a *better* way in C# though.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Apparently we can create a pointer to an integer and manipulate each of the bytes individually. Pretty cool :)

Comment: It is, but isn't it `unsafe`?

Comment: @M.Babcock: Yes. The whole class is `unsafe` so I didn't mark the function.

Answer (score 0):

I copied Mono's `GetInt32` and modified it slightly:

```
public override int GetInt24(byte[] data, int index)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    if (data.Length - index < 3)
        throw new ArgumentException("index");
    if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("index");

    int ret = 0;
    byte* b = (byte*)&ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        b[2 - i] = data[index + i];

    return ret;
}
```

Seems to work.

Comment: Strike that. I see it now. It's been a long day.